# Should wrappers component remind propTypes of wrapped components?

Tags: reactjs

When you create a component **A** which wraps a components **B** by adding some logic ? Should you remind required propTypes of **B** in **A** ?

Pratical example:

```
const HorizontalGauge = React.createClass({

  propTypes: {
    //Should I remind required propTypes of GenericHorizontalGauge ?
    showPercentage: PropTypes.bool,
  },

  _formatStackValuePercentage() {
    ...
  }

  render() {
    let { showPercentage, ...otherProps } = this.props;


    return (
      <GenericHorizontalGauge
        formatValue={showPercentage && this._formatValuePercentage}
        {...otherProps}
      />
   );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking if the `GenericHorizontalGauge` should have the same `propTypes` as `HorizontalGauge` since every prop is passed from `HorizontalGauge` to `GenericHorizontalGauge`?

In that case the answer is yes, they should. To avoid duplication, you can define the props in one place and reuse that. Something like this:

```
const HorizontalGauge = React.createClass({
  propTypes: GenericHorizontalGauge.propTypes,
  /* Other methods here */
});
```

Comment: Yeh that's what I though so in this case HorizontalGauge propTypes should be something like
`propTypes: {...GenericHorizontalGauge.propTypes, showPercentage: PropTypes.bool}`