# Checking PropTypes of inner React component as part of wrapper component

Tags: reactjs

I have Component B that contains Component A.  Component A has propTypes defined to validate its properties.  I'd like to have a property in Component B that represents the properties in Component A, validate them and reference them.  I can't seem to figure that out. Here's what I have so far (abstracted for simplicity of this discussion):

```
class ComponentB extends PureComponent {
    static propTypes = {
        componentAProperties: PropTypes.shape(ComponentA.propTypes)
        compBProp1: PropType.number,
        compBProp2: PropType.string,
        compBProp3: PropType.object
    }
    render() {
        const {componentAProperties, ...others} = this.props
        return (
            <ComponentB {...others}>
                <ComponentA {...componentAProperties} />
            </ComponentB
        )
    }
}

class ComponentA extends PureComponent {
    static propTypes = {
        compAProp1: PropTypes.string,
        compAProp2: PropTypes.number,
        compAProp3: PropTypes.oneOf(['cat', 'dog', 'mouse'])
        compAProp4: PropTypes.bool,
        compAProp5: PropTypes.object
    }
    render() {
        const {...others} = this.props
        return <ComponentA {...others} />
    }
}
```

The line in ComponentB containing PropTypes.shape(ComponentA.propTypes) does not throw any warning, but I can still pass bogus property values to ComponentA, so I feel like there's still something missing.  That is, I can write

```
<ComponentB componentAProperties={{compAProp2: 'hello'}} />
```

without warning or error even though compAProp2 is defined as a number.

(**Note:** I tested PropTypes.ComponentA, ComponentA.PropTypes and ComponentA.propTypes as the componentAProperties value, and all of them threw the console warning, "Failed prop type: ComponentB: prop type `componentAProperties` is invalid; it must be a function, usually from the `prop-types` package, but received `object`.)

I read that there are custom validators you can write, but those seem to work for only PropTypes.arrayOf() and PropTypes.objectOf() whereas ComponentA's propTypes are a shape.

**Other Questions I Referenced:**

- [React composition component proptypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41703724/react-composition-component-proptypes) 
  Why not: I want a specific property to reference the inner component, not just to spread the inner component's properties.
- [Should wrappers component remind propTypes of wrapped components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29919325/should-wrappers-component-remind-proptypes-of-wrapped-components)
  Why not: The suggested answer doesn't work.  It throws a warning, "Failed prop type: : prop type `<inner component>` is invalid; it must be a function, usually from the `prop-types` package, but received `object`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i see, your approach is already correct.
So i try it right away in JSFiddle.
I have fixed your "abstracted" code example so that it works without essentially changing anything.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gejimayu/cnhw4vzy/2/

I take this as an example.

`<ComponentB componentAProperties={{compAProp2: 'hello'}} />`

As you can see, if you open browser's console, you will see a proptype warning.

So there is nothing wrong with your approach.

However, if i change the prop-type package to the production build, it won't show any warning.

Hence i think it must have something to do with production/development build.
Proptypes will only show warning on development build.
So please do change your environment build to development if you wish to see any warning.

In addition to that, please use prop-type package if you haven't. https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types

React "native" support for prop-types has been stopped.
https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks!  It didn't occur to me that the issue could be in how the app is being built. (I'm very new to programming.)  I'll investigate, but because your JS Fiddle demonstrates that the code works, I've marked your answer as the solution.

Comment: As my code evolved, I needed the inner component to be determined at runtime.  I happened to use PropTypes.any as I was coding, and the validation of the inner component seems to work.  Check out https://jsfiddle.net/marniea/6j5xcg3m/  What do you think of that solution?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. On that case, you can use PropTypes.oneOfType([
  PropTypes.shape(ComponentA1.propTypes),
  PropTypes.shape(ComponentA2.propTypes)
]),

Comment: Yes, I thought that would work, but when I tried using oneOf, it gave me this error: Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `innerComponentProperties` of value `[object Object]` supplied to `ComponentB`, expected one of [{},{}].
    in ComponentB  See my JS Fiddle: jsfiddle.net/marniea/6j5xcg3m   I've updated it to use the oneOf method instead of PropTypes.any.

Comment: Here i've fixed it for you http://jsfiddle.net/gejimayu/each1nu8/2/. First, oneOf is for literal type like string or number, oneOfType is for proptype's type like Proptypes.number. Second, you should put ComponentA.propTypes inside of PropTypes.shape() to convert componentA proptypes into PropTypes's type.

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks so much!